# Xamarin Forms Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: xamarin.forms

When coding Xamarin Forms, most of the errors shows up as

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

This is not very helpful, and Im in no hurry getting the exceptions details. How can I update this Timeout to "as long as you need"?

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this when there is an exception on another thread/async stuff. Have you tried using the debugger with some breakpoints to see if you can find out what data is in your variables and what goes in/out of your functions.

Comment: yes, I guess youre right. I try to use async/await as much as possible. Yes, the way I solve it now is setting breakpoints all over the place stepping, and finally seeing the error. But if I could see the actual error message from the beginning I would easily save hours a week.

Comment: You could file a suggestion on the visual studio forums so they can pick it up in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

When I started working on Xamarin forms this issue was something that annoyed the life out of me.

And it's a real pain to catch the reason behind it as its so undescriptive that it makes me sick to the bones.

Now the fun part is the solution which is obvious so bear with me:

This issue is caused by the XAML side when using xamarin forms and usually tells you that you have done something wrong there how to know what you just did wrong? just put a `try/catch` around `InitializeComponent` and you can examine the exception, understand the reason behind it a tad bit better.

XAML is declarative which makes us believe that the order of attributes of a control does not matter. Unfortunately - since at some point the declarative XAML will be turned into a sequence of property assignments - it does and this is why your exception is thrown.

Revert in case of queries or if you unable to solve this.

Comment: I would actually strongly advise **not** doing this at all. Putting `try...catch`es around `InitializeComponent()` prevents the views from being initialised (if an exception is triggered), which means any reference to any XAML component will cause further errors in the rest of the code.

Comment: That is to just check what the exception is not to be forgotten there its like an obvious thing is it not? Secondly in case of any exceptions in your XAML the application will crash anyway so what is point of `"which means any reference to any XAML component will cause further errors in the rest of the code"` @Tom I mean i am curious do tell.

Comment: If you're putting it in for debug reasons **only**, then that may be a viable way of determining the XAML issue. Although, `XamlCompilation` would work better IMHO.

Comment: I would disagree with this actually there are certain things that Xaml compilation cannot find like for eg, outside of the tags try putting a `.` and then see what error you get even if you were einstein himself you won't understand the physics behind the error until you actually find it, Try catch on the other hand should never be on initliaze component agreed, i would say that avoid try catch as much as possible here in release for debug its okay..

Comment: Well, if you put `.` outside of tags in a XAML file, `XamlCompilation` will see that there is something wrong, but will display an irrelevant message like `Value cannot be null.` I think that's what you're talking about.

Comment: First of all, it will give you an error something like `Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ListNode' to type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IElementNode'.` now what happens is a newbie will never understand what is up here since there is no relevant message I would go as far as to say the message here literally means there is a casting issue and this is caused by a ` .` that is just outside the Tags the message is not self-explanatory at all. But try catch will tell you this is the issue or at least give you a line number.

Comment: Still, I do not think release apps should have a try-catch block on the `InitializeComponent` method it is for development understanding only that I recommend it and not only me almost every developer would.